# How can I get my checkbox data into text area box in html using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have a html form that has check box and text area. When I check the check box, I want it to be dynamically update the text area with its value. what am I doing wrong? here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Web page</title>
<script type="javascript">
   function changeTA() {
   var inputElements = document.getElementByName("favorite_pet");
       for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
           if(inputElements[i].checked){
               $('#ta').val($('#ta').val()+inputElements[i].value); 
     }
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
   <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_cat" value="Cats" onchange="changeTA()">Cats<br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_dog" value="Dogs" onchange="changeTA()">Dogs<br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_bird" value="Birds" onchange="changeTA()">Birds<br>  
       <br>  

   <textarea id="ta" rows="4" cols="50">
   </textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your code:

- You have a typo in `getElementByName`, use `getElementsByName`
- You're missing a closing bracket in your function
- Change `<script type="javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Your code should work with these 3 problems fixed:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Web page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeTA() {
        var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("favorite_pet");
        for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
           if(inputElements[i].checked){
               $('#ta').val($('#ta').val()+inputElements[i].value); 
              }
       }
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
   <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_cat" value="Cats" onchange="changeTA()">Cats<br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_dog" value="Dogs" onchange="changeTA()">Dogs<br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_bird" value="Birds" onchange="changeTA()">Birds<br>  
   <br>  

   <textarea id="ta" rows="4" cols="50">
   </textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrz1L4h9/

Comment: still didn't get the result I expected. the textarea box is blank

Comment: you're right, you're also missing a closing bracket in your script, I updated my answer :)

Comment: thank you. it s working in fiddle but not in chrome / IE. any idea? why?

Comment: no..what I meant is a webpage is supposed to be run on a browser directly without any tools like fiddle. it works in fiddle but not directly in the browser. any reason that you are aware of?

Comment: JSFiddle is not a tool to run your javascript code, it's just an "online IDE" that is great for sharing code snippets, all the code you write there runs on the browser.

Comment: did you try on the browser without fiddle?

Comment: I just did and it works, are you importing jQuery ? Is there any error logged in the console?

Comment: yes, it is imported. but i see errors in the console dont know why? Uncaught ReferenceError: changeTA is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Comment: it is the same though i posted a snip of the code as it is in my editor https://imgur.com/a/GxNcJOI

Comment: That's not the same as the code in the fiddle, this what it should look like: https://imgur.com/a/vJrZUAE